# List of scopes required for accessing google Cloud IAM policy through api call

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub, google-iam

I am trying to access my google Cloud IAM policy console by using a user's bearer/access code. I want to Grant permissions to the same user to create subscriptions to my topic the email address obtained in Step 1 to grant access rights to user to our topic To see the policy which is a collection of bindings that associate a member, such as a user account or service account, with a role. You can refer following url for details `https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access`. To update a policy for a resource by using the read-modify-write pattern. This means there are no distinct methods for creating, modifying, or revoking user access.

1. Instead, all modifications are made by:
   Reading the current policy by calling getIamPolicy() by following api `https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/gmail-trigger-1534948877977:getIamPolicy`
2. Editing the returned policy, either by using a text editor or programmatically, to add or remove any desired members and their role grants.
3. Writing the updated policy by calling setIamPolicy() by following api   `https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/gmail-trigger-1534948877977:setIamPolicy`.
   But in both cases I am getting following error :

   {
     "error": {
       "code": 403,
       "message": "The caller does not have permission",
       "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
     }
   }

I have used a list of scopes as I am doing some other operations also, a list of scopes used by me are :

```
https://mail.google.com/+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read-only
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly
https://mail.google.com/
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
```

My question is am I lacking with some scope or I have to do so by some other means. I can do that manually by going into console by I am not able to do so programatically.

Comment: Are you trying to modify a user's existing Access Token with additional scopes OR are you trying to modify the IAM roles for a user so that the next time they authenticate they have more privileges? Show the code that you are using in addition to the endpoints.

Comment: I am trying to modify the IAM roles for a user so that the next time they authenticate they have more privileges? In code i am just making rest api calls to above mentioned apis